# Ampersand causing returned text to be cut off in URL

Tags: php, urlencode

I have inherited several php scripts from the person who maintaned the code before. He had no programming experience and mostly threw things together the best he could. today I had to rewrite a plug-in file for wordpress and now I can't figure out what is going wrong.

The issue I am facing is that when diplaying the returned file names in the else statement that is part of the table (`<?php echo $result->display_name; ?>`) I get unexpected results. Let's say our database has a file called Black & White.pdf. Instead of returning the display_name "Black & White.pdf", it returns "Black". I have tried the following:

```
<?php echo htmlentities($result->display_name); ?>
```

and

```
<?php echo htmlspecialchars($result->display_name); ?>
```

Neither of which have produced the desired result. What is going wrong? Is this PHP ignorance on my part, or is this something about how WP returns the results (which I assume wouldn't make a difference since I don't believe that WP could change how php is parsed). For reference here is the code:

```
function display_files($assn_id) {
    global $wpdb;
    $second_db = new wpdb("xxxxxx", "xxxxxx", "xxxxxx", "xxxxxx");

    $results = $second_db->get_results("SELECT
        community_files.id,
        community_files.display_name,
        community_files.filename,
        community_files.sort,
        community_files.file_type
        FROM
        community_files
        WHERE
        community_files.comm_id = '".$assn_id."'
        ORDER BY
        community_files.sort ASC");

        if (!$results) {
            echo "<li>The next meeting has not been posted yet.</li>";
        } else {

            echo "<table>";
            // keeps getting the next row until there are no more to get

            foreach ($results as $result) {
                if (!$result->display_name) {
                    $display_name = str_replace("_", " ", $result->filename);
                    $display_name_fake = str_replace(" .", ".", $display_name);
                    $file_array[$x] = $result->id;
                } else {
                    $display_name = $result->display_name;
                    $display_name_fake = str_replace(" .", ".", $display_name);
                    $file_array[$x] = $result->id;
                } ?>
                    <tr>
                        <td>
                        <?php
                        if ($result->display_name == "") {
                        ?>
                            <a href="renamefiles.php?action=rename&amp;file_id=<?php echo $result->id; ?>&amp;filename=<?php echo $display_name; ?>&amp;assn_id=<?php echo $assn_id; ?>"><?php echo $display_name_fake; ?></a>
                        <?php
                        } else {
                        ?>
                            <a href="renamefiles.php?action=rename&amp;file_id=<?php echo $result->id; ?>&amp;filename=<?php echo $display_name; ?>&amp;assn_id=<?php echo $assn_id; ?>"><?php echo $result->display_name; ?></a>
                        <?php
                        }
                        ?>
                        </td>
                    </tr>
                <?php   
            }
            echo "</table>";
        }
}
```

Comment: ack... that looks like a sql injection "kick me" sign...

Comment: ^^ ... and `$wpdb` has a `prepare` method to help with prevent that.

Comment: Are you having this problem down towards the end where you are echoing this file name as part of the URL? You should have neither spaces or an unencoded `&` there. Try `var_dump($results)` right after you query and see if the whole string-- "Black & White.pdf"-- comes out of the DB?

Comment: You should also take a look at the rendered HTML code, it will give you insights as to what is wrong.

Comment: I did the var_dump and it is returning "Black & White.pdf". It's not a problem with what becomes part of the URL, it causes issues for what is displayed in the browser.

Comment: The html that is getting returned is     `<td><span style="font-weight:bold;">Original File Name:</span> </td><td><span style="color:#0066FF;">Black </span></td>`

Comment: That `span` is not in any of the code you posted. Where is that coming from?

Comment: Thanks for pointing out span. So I found the function that should be printing the original file name... But then as a test I decided to see what $_POST and $_GET were set to. I got this in $_GET: `array(5) { ["action"]=> string(6) "rename" ["file_id"]=> string(5) "24086" ["filename"]=> string(8) "Black " ["White_pdf"]=> string(0) "" ["assn_id"]=> string(2) "25" } ` Now I feel like I'm getting somewhere. How can I ensure that the ampersand isn't deleted when passed via $_GET?

Comment: Please review my second comment and reflect upon your claim that "It's not a problem with what becomes part of the URL". I will write up an answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It sounds like you need to [`urlencode`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.urlencode.php) that file name when you insert it into the URL you are constructing. Per a comment above not doing so is breaking your `GET` string.

```
array(5) { 
  ["action"]=> string(6) "rename" 
  ["file_id"]=> string(5) "24086" 
  ["filename"]=> string(8) "Black " 
  ["White_pdf"]=> string(0) "" 
  ["assn_id"]=> string(2) "25" 
}
```

This has led you to conclude that the code you posted is failing. It isn't. It is just constructing malformed HTML, which then fails when you click the like.

This code:

```
<a href="renamefiles.php?action=rename&amp;file_id=<?php echo $result->id; ?>&amp;filename=<?php echo $display_name; ?>&amp;assn_id=<?php echo $assn_id; ?>"><?php echo $result->display_name; ?></a>
```

Should be like this:

```
<a href="renamefiles.php?action=rename&amp;file_id=<?php echo $result->id; ?>&amp;filename=<?php echo urlencode($display_name;) ?>&amp;assn_id=<?php echo $assn_id; ?>"><?php echo $result->display_name; ?></a>
```

You will then need to [`urldecode`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.urldecode.php) `$_GET['filename']` when you process the request.

I would encourage you not to have spaces and special characters like `&` in your filename at all (if you actually are using this name as a filesystem file name). You are asking for trouble.

Comment: This worked perfectly. Thanks for explaining it in a clear way, I appreciate the help!

Comment: Why no more +1s? This seems to precisely answer the question.